# homeomorphism of same space

Tags: general-topology

If $(X,\mathcal T)$ and $(X,\bar{\mathcal T})$ are homeoporphic, isn't that $\mathcal T=\bar{\mathcal T}$?

I ask this question because of a theorem: If $(X,\mathcal T)$ be compact and $(X,\bar{\mathcal T})$ be Hausdorff, also given that $\bar{\mathcal T}\subseteq\mathcal T$, then $\mathcal T=\bar{\mathcal T}$.

Proof: consider the function $f:(X,\mathcal T)\to(X,\bar{\mathcal T})$ defined by $f(x)=x$. Then it is bijection. It is also continuous because  $\bar{\mathcal T}\subseteq\mathcal T$. By the property of functions from compact space to Hausdorff space, the function is a homeomorphism. So, $\mathcal T=\bar{\mathcal T}$.

I don't understand the last step that why homeomorphic means same topology.

Comment: If $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is compact, then every continuous mapping from $(X,\mathcal{T})$ to a Hausdorff space is closed. Thus in this case, every $\mathcal{T}$-closed set is also $\bar{\mathcal{T}}$-closed, hence $\mathcal{T}\subset \bar{\mathcal{T}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X=\{1,2\}$ we can have $\mathcal T=\{\emptyset, X, \{1\}\}$ and $\tilde{\mathcal T}=\{\emptyset, X, \{2\}\}$, so $(X,\mathcal T)\approx(X,\tilde{\mathcal T})$ via $1\leftrightarrow 2$ but $\mathcal T\ne\tilde{\mathcal T}$.

However, in the given special case where

1. $(X,\mathcal T)$ is compact
2. $(X,\tilde{\mathcal T})$ is Hausdorff
3. $\tilde{\mathcal T}\subseteq \mathcal T$

we have that $f\colon (X,\mathcal T)\to (X,\tilde{\mathcal T}), x\mapsto x$ is continuos by the third property: If $U\in \tilde{\mathcal T}$, then also $f^{-1}(U)=U\in\mathcal T$. So $f$ is a continuous bijection from a compact to a Hausdorff space, hence is a homeomorphism. But that means that the inverse map $g=f^{-1}$ is continuous and hence for $U\in\mathcal T$ we have that $g^{-1}(U)=U\in\tilde{\mathcal T}$, i.e. $\mathcal T\subseteq \tilde{\mathcal T}$. Together with the third property this means $\mathcal T=\tilde{\mathcal T}$.

Actually, the very last step "If the identity map $(X,\mathcal T)\to(X,\tilde{\mathcal T})$ is a homeomorphism, then $\mathcal T=\tilde{\mathcal T}$" should be the simplest part of the proof as more generally a map $(X,\mathcal T)\to(\tilde X,\tilde{\mathcal T})$ is a homeomorphism iff its induced map $\tilde {\mathcal T}\to\mathcal T$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $X=\{0,1\}$ and $\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset,\{0\},X\}$, $\mathcal{T}_0=\{\emptyset,\{1\},X\}$. Then, $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}_0$ are topologies on $X$. Also, the function $f:(X,\mathcal{T})\to (X,\mathcal{T}_0)$ with $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$ is a homeomorphism, but $\mathcal{T}\neq\mathcal{T}_0$.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that a continuous bijection is not necessarily a homeomorphism. The inverse function also has to be continuous. For example the map $g: [0,1) \rightarrow S^1$, $g(x) = e^{2 \pi i x}$ is a continuous bijection from $[0,1)$ to the unit circle, but it's not a homeomorphism.

For the inverse function $h=g^{-1}$ to be continuous, it means $h^{-1}(U)$ has to be open for every open set $U$ in the codomain of $h^{-1}$. But since $h^{-1}=g$, that's the same as saying $g(U)$ is open for every $U$ in the domain of $g$. In other words, for $h$ to be continuous, $g$ must be an open map. If $g$ is a bijection, this is the same as $g$ being a closed map (image of closed sets closed).

There's a well-known result that a continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is closed. In the case of your example, given that $f$ is a continuous bijection, that's enough to conclude that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Knowing that the identity map $f: (X,\mathcal{T}) \rightarrow (X,\mathcal{\bar{T}})$ is continuous is the same as saying for every set $U \in \bar{\mathcal{T}}$, $f^{-1}(U)=U$ belongs to $\mathcal{T}$. That shows $\bar{\mathcal{T}} \subseteq \mathcal{T}$. Once we show $f^{-1}$ is also continuous then we get $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \bar{\mathcal{T}}$.